# Definition of ETW macros DoTraceMessage, WPP_CLEANUP, WPP_INIT_TRACING?

Tags: macros, etw

When using the [*Windows software trace preprocessor*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556067%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (WPP) component of [*Event Tracing for Windows*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545699%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (ETW), you must include a file [that contains 3 macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541243%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

- [`WPP_INIT_TRACING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556191%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) macro activates software tracing
- [`DoTraceMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544918%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) macro to log trace messages
- [`WPP_CLEANUP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) macro deactivates software tracing

---

The include file containing these macros are generated *automatically* when you add the following to the bottom of a source file:

```
RUN_WPP= $(SOURCES)
```

Since these things are **macros**, they actually expand to do *something else*. i need an example of what these macro's expand to.

The reason i need a sample of these generated macros is that i do not own Visual Studio, nor am i writing in C/C++, or using a Microsoft compiler.

---

**Bonus Chatter**. The Microsoft SDK provides a [sample include file (`tracedrv.tmh`) that contains the macro definitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The definition of those macros is available in the .TMH file created by the WPP preprocessor for your file during compilation.

The ''RUN_WPP= $(SOURCES)'' line cause execution of the WPP preprocessor TraceWpp.exe executable which is included in the DDK. The TMH files are created in the obj directory.

Comment: i don't have access to a WPP preprocessor, or a file for it to compile; which is why i'm asking for one.

Answer (score 0):

To use WPP, Windows Driver Kit must be installed. Just [download WDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11800) and install it.

After installation, there is a buidable WPP sample driver at:

- C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\src\general\tracing\tracedrv

Those macros you are looking for can be found at:

- C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\bin\WppConfig\Rev1\km-init.tpl
- C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\bin\WppConfig\Rev1\um-init.tpl ... etc.